# Show Camera stream in Canvas / Video using Phonegap

Tags: cordova, camera, cordova-plugins

For Phonegap (Android), we are currently investigating the possibility to set the stream of the camera of an Android device as the source of a video element. A bit in the lines of gUM on webbrowsers.

We would like to build a video chat app with Phonegap.

The documentation only shows functions that call the native camera application, which is not what we are looking for.

Is showing the stream of the camera of an Android mobile device inside a HTML element with Phonegap possible?

Comment: We went with the crosswalk project (https://crosswalk-project.org/#documentation/cordova) to have full access to gUM.

Answer (score 3):

Plugin name :  [phonegap-plugin-media-stream](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-media-stream).

Use this plugin and add video tag in HTML and use JS code. It works for me.

**HTML** :  video tag

**JS** :

```
var constraints = navigator.mediaDevices.getSupportedConstraints();
alert(constraints);

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    'video': {
        'facingMode': 'environment'
    }
}).then(function(mediaStream) {
    var mediaControl = document.querySelector('video');
    mediaControl.srcObject = mediaStream;
    mediaControl.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaStream);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you have a look at getUserMedia
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NavigatorUserMedia.getUserMedia

and https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/getUserMedia

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking the time to answer this question. We tried using gUM and other Camera related API's in the Phonegap framework but did not offer what we were looking for. We found a solution in a project that combines a later version of the Chromium Webview with Cordova. (https://crosswalk-project.org/#documentation/cordova)